# Wrapping void pointer in C++/CLI and C#

Tags: c++-cli

I am working on C++/CLI wrapper for C static libary that is eventually used in C# application.

I have function like this in C Library.

```cpp
long SubscriveEvent(void* handle,device name ,....);

long StartCaptureViceo(handle,...,...);
```

Here StartCaptureViceo () will use the handle from SubscriveEvent()

I nee to maintain some variable in  C# for this void 
Now what data type i should use in C++/CLI to Retain.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 4):

[`System::IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)